# Second Generate AC command returns 6A86 after successful First Generate AC command in EMV transaction

Tags: smartcard, iso, emv, contactless-smartcard, mastercard

I am currently implementing an EMV transaction and have encountered an issue where my Second Generate AC command is returning a "6A86" response code when called immediately after a successful First Generate AC command.

My First Generate AC command returns a successful response of "77299F2701809F360201699F2608CA3559C737FD8E6A9F10120110A00003220000000000000000142800FF9000". Here's the APDU command for the First Generate AC command:

"80AE800042000000000002000000000000056604800008000566230425001CB0FCE92200000000000000000000410300100545000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Following the successful response from the First Generate AC command, I immediately send the Second Generate AC command, which returns a "6A86" response code. Here's the APDU command for the Second Generate AC command:

"80AE4001106D0000000000000000000000000000FF303004800008001CB0FCE9000000000000000000"

I have tried checking for possible errors in the data elements used in the Second Generate AC command, but I cannot seem to identify any issues. I am wondering what could be causing the "6A86" response code and how I can resolve this issue to continue with the EMV transaction.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: P2 has to be 00, right ?

Comment: I don't think so, however, I get same response even with "00"

Comment: I could be wrong, but it is not assumed that the second gen AC will be executed because normally for contactless payments we just tap the pos device and then remove the card. So bascially we do not wait until the terminal will receive the ARPC from the issuer to validate it on the chip.

Comment: Interesting take, @user478681, how then would the TC and cryptogram be retrieved?

Comment: couple of quotes from M/Chip Requirements - for Contact and Contactless manual:

For EMV mode transaction authorization responses, the issuer should not generate Issuer
Authentication Data or issuer script messages, because the contactless-enabled terminal is not
able to pass Issuer Authentication Data or issuer script messages to the contactless card or
contactless payment device.
...
For contactless payments, the cryptogram in the clearing is the cryptogram generated in the
first GENERATE AC Response.

Comment: Okay, could you share links to these documents please

Comment: no, unfortunately it is not a public document